# webpage on different screens

Tags: css, screen, html

I have a [webpage](http://ferhan.ferohost.com) made by me. At this moment, on different screens, it is looking pretty different.

On my computer the "See More" text is looking like this (which is I want):

FIRST IMAGE:

[image]

Whereas on another computer(with different screen size), its looking in this way(which is not I want):

SECOND IMAGE: [image]

In this SECOND IMAGE, the "See More" text is not in a single line for some reasons (on different screen) which is not I want.

Note: I have marked "See More" text with pen so that its easy for the readers to look for the text.

The CSS codes which I am using for the "See More" text are:

```
.development-text .right-side-bottom {
    padding-left: 220px;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

I am wondering what changes I need to make in CSS so that its look same on different screen size computers.

Answer (score 0):

In this class `.development-text .right-side-bottom` remove `padding-left: 220px;` and add `text-align: right;`.This changes you need.

```
.development-text .right-side-bottom {
  font-style: italic;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem, this should solve it:

```
.development-text .right-side-bottom {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Yet, this is only a small problem compared to the full set of problems that you will encounter in the process of coding a responsive page. I really recommend you take a course in responsive design, such as [Learn Responsive Design](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-responsive-design)